# Binding DataGrid ItemSource to CollectionView does not work

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I am working on a small WPF project and need to bind a CollectionView to a DataGrid. Therefore, I call the following command in a method to set the CollectionView's data:

```html
 BlInvoicesCollectionView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(BlInvoices);
BlInvoicesCollectionView.Filter = FilterBlInvoices;
```

BlInvoices is just a normal list with items of a model I created. When I debung the code, the CollectionView contains the values it should. However, the Items are not displayed in the DataGrid and I couldn't figure out why yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue by implementing a new property of type CollectionView, which is calls the PropertyChanged everytime it is set.

```html
public CollectionView BlInvoicesCollectionView { get{ return blInvoicesCollectionView; } 
            set { blInvoicesCollectionView = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BlInvoicesCollectionView)); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a List of type BlInvoices (`List<BlInvoices>`) called `BlInvoicesCollection`, then you can simply use:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = BlInvoicesCollection;
```

Comment: Yes, but to make filtering easier, a CollectionView is the better choice in this case. Futhermore, the List does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, which is necessary for the MVVM pattern.